# Possible missing corner test case

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

for the following question i have tried and modified my code for several test cases but still i am getting wrong answer on an online judge. Please tell me the test case i am missing of any possible error in my code that i am not able to see

the question :

The chef is preparing a birthday cake for one of his guests,
and his decided to write the age of the guest in candles on the cake.
There are 10 types of candles, one for each of the digits '0' through '9'.
The chef has forgotten the age of the guest, however, so doesn't know whether he has enough candles of the right types.
For example, if the guest were 101 years old, the chef would need two '1' candles and one '0' candle.
Given the candles the chef has, your task is to determine the smallest positive integer that cannot be represented with those candles.
Input:

Input will begin with an integer T≤100, the number of test cases.
Each test case consists of a single line with exactly 10 integers, each between 0 and 8, inclusive.
The first integer of each test case represents the number of '0' candles the chef has,
the second integer represents the number of '1' candles the chef has, and so on.
Output:

For each test case, output on a single line the smallest positive integer that cannot be expressed with the given candles.
Sample input:

3

2 1 1 4 0 6 3 2 2 2

0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

2 2 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1

Sample output:

4
10
22

and here is my code for the above question :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int arr[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        int min_value=arr[1],min_index=1;
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(min_value>arr[i])
            {
                min_value=arr[i];
                min_index=i;
            }
        }
        if(min_value==0)
            cout<<min_index<<endl;
        else if(min_value!=0&&arr[0]==0)
            cout<<10<<endl;
        else if(min_value!=0&&arr[0]!=0)
        {
            if(arr[0]<min_value)
                cout<<min_index*pow(10,arr[0]+1);
            else if(arr[0]>=min_value)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<=min_value;i++)
                    cout<<min_index;
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also tell me whether finding the minimum value excluding the 0th order index and including the 0th order index will have any effect on the answer for the question?

Answer (score 1):

This for loop doesn't do what you think it does:

```
        for(int i=0;i<min_value;i++)
            age=min_index*10+min_index;
```

Comment: please check my new solution and tell me the error i am still getting a wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

What happens if arr[0] == min_value?  eg

2

1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

5 5 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

Your current code says:

```
        if(arr[0]<min_value)
            cout<<min_index*pow(10,arr[0]+1);
        else if(arr[0]>min_value)
        {
        ...
        }
```

Comment: i have edited the code accordingly... but i am still getting a wrong answer

Comment: No you haven't.  The answer for the case `1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` is 11.  Your edited code currently says it's 100.

Comment: i have changed the code again and for your test case it is giving 11 as the answer but it is still giving me a wrong answer on codechef

Comment: Well, I'm not sure.  We found and fixed a lot of issues.  Now the only code that concerns me right now is this: `           cout<<min_index*pow(10,arr[0]+1);`

pow is for floats, not integers.  Maybe there's a rounding issue here?  I might be missing something else, though.